# Change font size and weight of text in navigation menu on WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, size

I am looking to change the font size and weight of the navigation menu items on my WordPress site, I am using The Company theme, but I can't seem to figure out the CSS required

My site is www.thepowerwithin.org.uk

I am looking to make the items in the main menu at the top bigger and bold

Comment: what did you try? Please write your css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have reviewed your question. I think you want to apply CSS only on  `main-menu anchor text` not on `sub-menu anchor text`. If I am right then you can do as:

```
ul.menu:not(.sub-menu) > li > a {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

You should use `children-selector >` to apply CSS only on the direct `children of ul`

When use `ul.menu:not(.sub-menu)` it ignores sub-menu ul of li.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is learn how to use the developer tools in [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) or [Chrome](https://developers.chrome.com/devtools/) or [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/) or [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673541(v=vs.85).aspx) to see what's loading on your site and how to work with and change the CSS and HTML. Dev tools allows you to make temporary changes to the locally cached browser copy of the site. You can then add the CSS changes to the theme, either by adding new CSS in theme options or to the style sheet.

If the theme allows you to add custom CSS to modify the menu, that's good. If not, make a child theme so you don't lose your changes when the theme is updated. See [Child Themes « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)